# Toolbar junto com TabHost

Tags: android

Olá. Criei duas abas na minha aplicação. Pedido abertos e Pedidos Fechados. Mas nesta activity O Toolbar não pega.

[image: Abas]

Código:

```
public class PedidoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedido);

    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("EM ABERTO");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("EM ABERTO" ,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("FECHADO");
    spec2.setIndicator("FECHADO" ,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);


    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);


}
```

Nesta tela não fica igual à outras, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de adicionar um toolbar nesta tela também.
Pois neste toolbar quero adicionar o botão voltar.

Comment: Poste o código do xml dela.

Answer (score 0):

gostava de poder comentar, pq a resposta seria curta, mas nao posso pois no so pt nao tenho repotacao suficiente.

Um concelho meu e criares uma `TabbedActivity` com `Action Bar Tabs` esta atividade tem uma `ViewPager` e uma `toolbar` .

Acho que te facilitaria muito o trabalho, alguma dúvida diz!

Bom trabalho

Comment: Não consegui compreender muito bem, você poderia me dar mais dicas? Se possível pode responder em outra língua, talvez inglês. Eu compreendo bem o Inglês. Obrigado.

Comment: Sou portugues, vou te explicar de forma muito resumida:

Existe uma atividade chamada Tabbed activity, usa essa atividade para conseguires o pretendido.

essa atividade contem: tabHost, viewPager, toolbar e o fba (floatting button)

Explora um pouco essa atividade, é muito fácil de usar e prático, se tiveres alguma dúvida sobre essa atividade diz